# How to set commands for unrecognised file type

Tags: vimrc, command-line, autocmd, filetype

I want to set some commands for specific filetypes. For example an abbreviation:

```
:iabbr Sb SameBatch
```

The files have extension like `.data`, `.pro`. Their grammar, syntax-highlighting are defined in the framework. I am unaware of those things. Those files contain variables and their values for Perl scripts.

I tried

```
:au FileType data iabbr di ditto
```

But it doesn't work.

I thought that the extension is the file type of a file. Is it wrong and how to get it worked?

Comment: What's missing is a way for Vim to recognize the "data" filetype. You will have to add something like: `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.data set filetype=data`. See also [this link](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/44.html)

Comment: Run `:set filetype`. That will tell you what Vim thinks is the filetype.

Comment: @muru : I gave that command and found the type to be conf. When I give :au FileType conf set command, it works. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `BufEnter` autocommand event like this:

```
autocmd! BufEnter *.data :iabbr <buffer> di ditto
```

The abbreviation will be created when you enter a buffer which is named anything followed by `.data` and will exists only in this buffer thanks to `<buffer>`.

To answer more precisely the comment of @SibiCoder I'll detail the line:

- `BufEnter` trigger the command when a the user enter a buffer.
- `*.data` restrict the execution of the autocommand to files ending with `.data` this way when you enter a file named `foo.c` or `bar.sh` the autocommand is not trigger.
- `:iabbr <buffer> di ditto` is the command to execute and because of the `<buffer>` argument the abbreviation will be defined only for the current buffer.

See [`:h autocommand-events`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocommand-events) and [`:h :abbreviate-<buffer>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:abbreviate-%3Cbuffer%3E)

Comment: I thought about this, but there may be an edge case when you define a special filetype for a file extension, i.e. with an autocommand `autocmd! bufreadpost *.gs set filetype=javascript` Here the extension is `gs` but the filetype is `javascript`

Comment: //will exist only in this buffer // what does this mean? I thought this abbreviation will work in any buffer. Does this bufenter trigger every time when a file of this type is edited?

Comment: @SibiCoder yes. This way, a buffer for a `.sh` file, for example, wouldn't have this abbreviation. Keeps your abbreviations and maps clean.

Comment: @SibiCoder: muru is right, see the edit of my answer for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Use a function for this:

```
function! FTManage()
  let l:filetype = &filetype
  if l:filteype == 'data'
      " do stuff
  endif
endfunction

autocmd! FileType * call FTManage()
```

Here you pass through the function when the filetype change, so you can filter by filetype and call custom commands.

The main difference between statox's answer and this one is the type of filter. You can filter by file extension, but for some cases it's not relevant (because you can have an autocommand that change the filetype on read), so you can listen for the Filetype event and filter afterward.

Comment: The only "issue" of this answer is exactly the fact that Vim may not know anything about i.e. the `*.data` extension of a file, so the `filetype` may be not set up correctly, or at all.

Comment: Right, in which case, statox's answer is better :)